# Extracting images from an Excel file (xlsx) using PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can I read images from excel file using PHPExcel and save the images in the server and display them? The extension of the file is .xlsx.

My code:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();
    }

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can edit your question to let us see your code.

Comment: I copied my code... You can see it below.

Comment: You should edit the question itself, adding the code. I've just did it for you, so please remove the answer that you posted to show us your code.

Answer (score 6):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection()
```

will return an ArrayObject of all the image objects in the active worksheet.

These objects will be either PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing or PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing objects: you can identify which using [is_a()][1]. You can then use the methods appropriate to that class (as described in the API) either to read the image data from file (for PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing objects) or directly from the PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing object itself. The getName() and getDescription() methods can be used to retrieve the relevant values fro the image object.

Note that it's also possible to have image objects associated with print headers:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->getImages()
```

can be used to retrieve images from the header/footer. This is an array of PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooterDrawing objects. All the PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing methods can be used to extract the image file from these objects.

**EDIT**

Spoonfeeding time.

This will extract all images from the currently active worksheet, and write them to files on the server.

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

$i = 0;
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        switch ($drawing->getMimeType()) {
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_PNG :
                    $extension = 'png'; break;
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_GIF:
                    $extension = 'gif'; break;
            case PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_JPEG :
                    $extension = 'jpg'; break;
        }
    } else {
        $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(),'r');
        $imageContents = '';
        while (!feof($zipReader)) {
            $imageContents .= fread($zipReader,1024);
        }
        fclose($zipReader);
        $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
    }
    $myFileName = '00_Image_'.++$i.'.'.$extension;
    file_put_contents($myFileName,$imageContents);
}
```

Files are named

```
00_Image_n.extension
```

where n is a number starting from 1, and extension is the appropriate extension (png,jpg,gif, whatever) for the image type.

Comment: I already has been read this answer, but I didn't understand it...
this is my code but I don't know how to continue and it isn't for xls exstantion
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();
    }

}

Comment: What don't you understand about it? Calling this gives you an array of image objects. Depending on the type of image object, you use either getImageResource() to retrieve a bytestream of raw image data or getIndexedFilename() and read the returned file to get the image

Comment: But it isn't for xlsx exstantion

Comment: This code find and export all images....but with size 0 !! 
Any idea ???